# Custom Tallis and Tefillin Bag makers

Tags: product-recommendation, tefilin, tallit-gadol, protective-casing

As some of you may know, I was in Israel for awhile. While I was there, I decided to look for a set of bags with a nesiyat kapayim design (hands in the position used for duchaning, similar to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_salute)) on the front and I could not find one in Geula or the Midrachov (Yerushalayim).

This got me to wondering: I had heard from a friend that his tefillin bags were a custom design, although I have no clue where they're from.

Could anyone give me a recommendation for a studio where I could order custom tallit/tefillin bags from, preferably in the eastern US?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen non-custom bags with such hands. (Non-custom, because I'm pretty sure I've seen more than one with the same design.) But have no idea whether or how they can be obtained now.

Comment: @msh210, Do you see any of the owners often? Could you ask them?

Comment: I don't think so, though I don't recall now who they are. If I see one, I'll ask, _bl"n_.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt IIRC, the "big" Judaica store in Brookline is called "Hamakor". Don't they also make customized tallit bags besides their other beautiful overpriced Judaica ?(I have a clay Kiddush cup from them.)

Comment: @DanF, I don't know about Hamakor, but we do have Kolbo and the Israel Book Shop. Kolbo might make it, although I'm sure that IBS doesn't have it, having looked there in the past. If they did, it would probably be twice the cost of anywhere else, some of my questions about ona'ah were inspired by them.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Ah, correct! It was Kolbo. Maybe Hamakor was located somewhere else? I should explore that. Anyway, see my answer, below, about Zion Tallis. Something tells me that there is at least 1 store in Williamsburg that also does this. There's a Satmar man who goes to the shul next to me. B"N, if you haven't found an idea by then, if I see him this Shabbat, I'll ask him.

Comment: @DanF There's a Judaica store called HaMakor Gallery in Skokie near Chicago. Maybe you're thinking of that one?

Comment: I have a friend who will be making aliya soon. He currently lives in Canada and he is a leatherworker. Chersicola@yahoo.com is my email. Message me your info and i will see if he is interested and shadchan you

Answer (score 1):

At ajudaica.com you have the [this option](http://www.ajudaica.com/Jerusalem-Kohen-Blessing-Tallit-and-Tefillin-Bag-Set/item15028) or [this option](http://www.ajudaica.com/Kohens-Blessing-Tallit-and-Tefillin-Bag-Set-Silver/item15024).

At modaica.com you have [this option](http://modaica.com/judaica-21/talit/talit-and-tefilin-bag/burgundy-colored-kohen-talit-and-tefillin-bag-gold-lettering.html).

Prestige Embroidery does all types of custom bags. They are located at 474 Albany Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11203, info@prestigeembroidery.com, Tel: 347-663-2424

Comment: I guess I should have specified, I meant yadei kohanim, rather than the text of Birchat Kohanim

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt: I understood what you were asking. I gave you the third choice where they can make anything you desire.

Comment: Gershon - amazing what you find is located fairly close to you. This address sounds like it's in Crown Heights. I never heard of this place. But, it's something I'll keep in mind. I may want a custom *atarah*, and my wife may want a tablecloth. Funny... I should spend on her first!

Answer (score 1):

go to the chosson place they are AMAZING i made my Custom Tallis and tefillin bags there and i am very very happy. 
http://lavlarstam.blogspot.com/2012/02/custom-leather-bags.html
tell 917-620-6947

Comment: +1 Hey welcome to the site. Thanks for the answer. Consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site

Answer (score 0):

My sons got theirs custom made by Barbara Ladin Fisher of [Fisher Judaica](http://bfisherjudaica.com/tallis-bags/), Phone: (404) 321-7723.

(The top middle picture is my son's!)

Comment: I like your son's name (although it's funny seeing the name of a Sephardi rishon right next to a Jeckisch surname). Also, when did you start wearing a schtreimel?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - LOL! It's my Mechutan's schtreimel - from the fun part of my daughter's wedding - at the last dance. As my kids said, the tie is a giveaway that it's not real. :-)

Comment: Mazal tov, Danny.

Comment: In relation to the tie, I have seen some chassidim wear them.

Answer (score 0):

Though I work near there, I haven't walked on the Lower East Side recently to see if [Zion Talis](http://www.ziontalis.com/about.php) is still there. I'm assuming from the web site that they still exist, and they make great quality items, from what I recall. I never bought a personalized tallit bag, but I have shopped there a few times many years ago. You may want to contact them.

Comment: I didn't see on their website. I might email them, although I have a suspicion that they don't, based on the number of places I looked in Geula and they fact that NYC is bechutz la'aretz.

Answer (score 0):

One of my shul congregants, whose name is Asher, wears a beautiful tallit with a crocheted verse of the tribe of Asher from Moshe's blessing at the end of Devarim. I asked him where he had his tallit made. He emailed me a few days ago and recommended [this web site](http://www.shirleywaxman.com). I know nothing more about them other than the few pics I saw and my admiration of the tallit the congregant wears which is real "eye candy". So, I sense that this place would do an excellent job customizing what you need.

- Behatzlacha